# Javascript access to IE 11 DOM properties: InvalidStateError

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I'm trying to use a module named domjson - it provides a JSON representation of the DOM. Works great except for a curious stoppage in IE 11. A function within domjson is passed a node then iterates the node's properties. While iterating the properties, IE 11 stops and reports InvalidStateError. Here's a modification of the function:

```
var copyJSON = function (node, opts) {
        var copy = {};

            let nodePropertyNames = [];

            for (var n in node) {
                nodePropertyNames.push(n);
            } // for

            nodePropertyNames.forEach(function (propertyName) {

                console.log(node); //  
                console.log(propertyName); // 
                console.log(node[propertyName]); // 
                console.log('========================================\n\r')

            }) // foreach

        copy = boolFilter(copy, opts.domProperties);
        return copy;
    };
```

After iterating through most of the node's properties successfully, IE errors at node[propertyName]. At the error iteration, propertyName is "DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE". I can successfully log node['DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE'], with a value of 10.

Any thoughts or clues?

Comment: It looks like the while you are iterating one of the DOM nodes are no longer in the tree, because if I remember correctly that's when you get this error. I would check if the DOM nodes are there, and only remove them after iterating.

Comment: interesting. the error happens on the first node that I pass to domjson, I'm starting at HTML. I hope that I can figure this out, domjson would be very helpful for my current project

Comment: Are you running this function after the load event or beforeunload event ?

Comment: document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
 console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed 2");
 var domasjson = domJSON.toJSON(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]);

Comment: what happens when you change "DOMContentLoaded" to "load"?

Comment: I tried to format that as code, maybe can't in comments. Oddly, I ran it after lunchtime and now it's getting as far as the HEAD node.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177380/discussion-between-ted-fitzpatrick-and-ibowankenobi).